# How to make TinyMCE popups responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE 4.2.5, I noticed that all the popups are not responsive, can anybody help me to make the **popups** responsive.
By the way I am using 'code' plugin' :

```
  code_dialog_width: 1300,
  code_dialog_height: 700,
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean with responsive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make TinyMCE Responsive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991548/how-to-make-tinymce-responsive)

Comment: Thariama- "Responsive Web Design is about using CSS and HTML to resize, hide, shrink, enlarge, or move the content to make it look good on any screen", in my case, I want the width and height of the popup to be in percentage .

Comment: Gigala- it is not duplicate, I am asking about responsive popups not responsive editors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Make TinyMCE's modal dialogs Responsive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735352/how-to-make-tinymces-modal-dialogs-responsive)